# Solving an ODE with the implicit midpoint method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I've to solve this differential system: ($g=9.81$)

$y''(t) =-g  sin(y(t))$

$y'(0)=0$

$y(0)=\pi/3$

I had to solve it with the implicit midpoint rule:
$y_{n+1}=y_n + \frac{k}{2}f(t_n+\frac{k}{2},\frac{y_n+n_{n+1}}{2})$.

Here is the plot I got: [image: x-axis=t, y-axis=y(t)]

I think it's correct, since if I evaluate in $0$, I got $y''(0) =-gsin(\frac{\pi}{3})=-g\frac{\sqrt(3)}{2}<0$, so the numerical solution has the right convexity.
Are there other 'heuristic' consideration that I can do to be almost sure I got the right numerical solution? 
Maybe I could expand $sin(y(t))$ with Taylor and truncate at $\frac{y(t)^5}{120}$.

Thanks to everyone ;)

---

**Edit**

Using the advice of @ Gribouillis, I plotted the energy $E=(y')^2 - 2*g*cos(y)$, and since $\frac{dE}{dt} =0$, then its plot has to be constant, and it's what happens:

[image: The red line is $E$]

Comment: There is an invariant energy $E = (y')^2-2g \cos(y)$. You could perhaps plot this energy to see if it remains approximately constant.

Comment: I plotted it, but it's not approximately constant. How can I show that $E$ is an invariant energy?

Comment: Compute $\frac{d E}{d t}$. The equation is the [pendulum equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics))

Comment: Oh okay, I got it, the derivative is $0$ so it's constant. But how did you see that expression for $E$ ? 
Anyway, I made a mistake writing the expression for $E$ in Octave, now it has a constant value ;)

Comment: Multiply the equation with $2y'$ and integrate.

Comment: This energy has a physical interpretation. The kinetic energy is $(y')^2/2$, the gravitational potential energy is $-g \cos(y)$.

Comment: Okay, everything is clear now ;) Thanks so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Multiply by $y'$

$$y'y''=-g\sin y\,y'$$

and integrate

$$y'^2-0=2g\left(\cos \frac\pi3-\cos y\right).$$

The final solution will require an elliptic integral of the first kind.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+2g%2Fsqrt(1%2F2-%5Ccos+y)